# Copying two arrays into one array

Tags: java, arrays

The question is to write a program which takes two arrays of 10 integers each, a and b. c is an array with 20 integers. The program should put array a and b into the array c, the first 10 integers of c from array a, the  latter 10 from b. Then the program should display c. This is the code i have so far. It prints the values from arrayA into arrayC but i dont know how to print the values from arrayB into arrayC without overriding the information already in arrayC (arrayB).

```
public class questionTwo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] arrayA = {31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58, 57};
    int [] arrayB = {9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2};
    int [] arrayC = new int [20];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
      arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++)
    {
      int element = 9;
      arrayC[element] = arrayB[i];
      element++;
    }


    System.out.println("The values of ArrayC are: ");

    for(int val : arrayC)
    {
      System.out.println(val);
    } 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Before explaining how you might fix your current code, I would first suggest you create `arrayC` using the lengths of `arrayA` and `arrayB` (here that has the same *practical* result, but it has the advantage that you can add more elements to `arrayA` or `arrayB` without modifying the code). Next, in real code, I would use `System.arraycopy` to perform the copies. And use `Arrays.toString(int[])` for printing. Like,

```
int[] arrayA = { 31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58, 57 };
int[] arrayB = { 9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2 };
int[] arrayC = new int[arrayA.length + arrayB.length];
System.arraycopy(arrayA, 0, arrayC, 0, arrayA.length);
System.arraycopy(arrayB, 0, arrayC, arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayC));
```

As for your original code, use `arrayA.length` and `i` to get the correct offset. Like,

```
int[] arrayC = new int[arrayA.length + arrayB.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    arrayC[i + arrayA.length] = arrayB[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You were really close! Your second loop initializes `element` to 9 every time, while you should only assign it to 10 once at the beginning:

```
int element = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++)
{
  arrayC[element] = arrayB[i];
  element++;
}
```

Comment: "It worked!": are you sure?  You should have gotten  `31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58, 57, 9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2` for your final result, but I'll bet you got  `31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58,9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2, 0` instead.  `element` should have started off at 10 (or better yet, `arrayA.length`, not 9.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that mistake, so I set it to 10 and it worked

Comment: Good catch @KevinAnderson

Answer (score 1):

Make your function dynamic while you need to add more item into your arrays. I did not test yet, but I hope it work.

```
public class questionTwo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] arrayA = {31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58, 57};
    int [] arrayB = {9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2};
    int [] arrayC = new int [arrayA.length + arrayB.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
      arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];

    int element = arrayA.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++)
    {
      arrayC[element+i] = arrayB[i];
    }

    System.out.println("The values of ArrayC are: ");

    for(int val : arrayC)
    {
      System.out.println(val);
    } 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second loop is wrong. You can use the follow code:

```
int [] arrayA = {31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58, 57};
int [] arrayB = {9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2};
int [] arrayC = new int [20];

System.arraycopy(arrayA, 0, arrayC, 0, arrayA.length);
System.arraycopy(arrayB, 0, arrayC, arrayA.length, arrayB.length);

System.out.println("The values of ArrayC are: ");

for(int val : arrayC) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is incorrect because you are setting `element` to `9` within the loop each time; thus, its value is always reset upon beginning the next iteration. You could move it outside the loop to achieve the result you're looking for. Also, I'd recommend constructing `arrayC` based on the lengths of `arrayA` and `arrayB`, that way you can combine array's of any length.

In addition, I'd also recommend moving the code to combine the arrays to a method to keep things clean and reusable for future endeavors.

```
public class questionTwo {

  private static int[] combineArrays(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
    int[] arrayC = new int[arrayA.length + arrayB.length];
    int idx = 0;

    for (int x : arrayA) {
       arrayC[idx] = x;
       idx++;
    }

    for (int x : arrayB) {
       arrayC[idx] = x;
       idx++;
    }

    return arrayC;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arrayA = {31, 14, 5, 12, 50, 80, 100, 29, 58, 57};
    int[] arrayB = {9, 13, 156, 78, 36, 46, 86, 98, 63, 2};

    int[] arrayC = combineArrays(arrayA, arrayB);

    System.out.println("The values of ArrayC are: ");

    for(int val : arrayC) {
      System.out.println(val);
    } 
  }

}
```

Also, it is often considered a poor practice to use Java's primitive arrays. Check out `List` and related objects for more flexible and full-featured options.